# Xfce 4.12: How to configure window switcher dialog (Alt-Tab) to use List mode?

Tags: xfce

How to configure window switcher dialog (Alt-Tab) to use List mode in Xfce 4.12? Modes are mentioned at http://www.xfce.org/about/tour but I found no such setting.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmXIejvZciA#t=02m00s

Go to:

Applications -> settings -> Settings Manager -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Cycling -> Cycle through windows in a list